# Meaning of zero "0" value in raster layer produced by Soil Texture Classification tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, saga, soil, soilgrids

How to interpret zero "0" value in raster layer produced by Soil Texture Classification tool in QGIS? It cannot be found in [classification table](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/grid_analysis_14.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out!

Zero "o" value is simply the value one "1" in [classification table](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/grid_analysis_14.html). Classification is just shifted up a bit.

I found it by using [soil texture calculator](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/survey/?cid=nrcs142p2_054167) with values from random chosen pixels in two different raster layers (clay and sand). For "safety reasons" calculation is manually checked and confirmed using [USDA texture classification table](http://www.fao.org/tempref/FI/CDrom/FAO_Training/FAO_Training/General/x6706e/x6706e06.htm).